# IPhone File Server & Client to Create Proxy Alternative to Personal Hotspot Tethering

Tags: iphone, wifi, cellular-data, tethering, ftp

Assumptions:

1. I have the latest iPhone with unlimited fast Internet through my cellular network provider.
2. I have a new Mac.
3. My iPhone prevents me from using my wireless data using my Mac when I set up a personal hotspot.
4. I have no other Internet connection.

---

Technique that needs improvement:

First I set up an ad-hoc network using my Mac and connect to it using my iPhone. Then I use the GoodReader app to run a server (this is a GoodReader feature) on my iPhone to which I can connect over my ad-hoc network by doing Go > Connect to Server... in Finder on my Mac. Once mounted, I can manipulate files in the GoodReader app storage just like a local folder on my Mac. From the Good Reader app I can then upload my files to Dropbox which syncs with my online storage and have access to the files online.

---

What I Want:

I want to find an app for my iPhone that will run a file server of some sort to which I can connect with my Mac. I want that app to then transfer files to an online file server (preferably using SFTP), automatically (or with minimal manual help). In essence this would have the effect of me being able to upload files over SFTP to a remote location using a Mac that is offline with an iPhone that is online. I'm basically looking for an alternative to tethering. The Mac -> GoodReader -> Dropbox -> Internet example proves this is possible but it has too many manual steps. I want something more streamlined.

Do you know of any apps or techniques that can work for me?

Comment: what exactly prevents you from using your iPhone as a Hotspot? It must be possible (i use it on a dayly basis) or do you just not want it that way?

Comment: It is possible -- I just don't want to do it that way. I plead the 5th as to why not.

Comment: but as i know using goodreader/dropbox e.g also uses your data connection.

Comment: My service provides unlimited LTE and up to 5GB of Hotspot. They are metered separately.

Comment: Ok if you say that i take it, although i never heard this before. So maybe You can cut a few manual steps if you use itunes on your pc to directly put the files into your dropbox app on the phone. Or you should take a look at GoodSync maybe that is useable http://www.goodsync.com/de/platforms/ios-server

Comment: another quick point you should check first: in our country tere is a second provider not mine, which also has hotspot restrictions but in there case it is meant to be the useage of there public wlan hotspots at trainstations e.g. so maybe that is also the case on your provider.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a few apps in the App Store that claim to be both an FTP client and server. That means you can run a server on an iPhone, connect to it from a Mac, transfer files to my phone, and then to a remote server (or vice versa). This would greatly simplify the process.

The apps are:

- FTP On The Go Pro
- Easy FTP Pro
- FilesConnect
- FTPManager
- iStorage 2

I believe there are others but these clearly explained that they include a server and client.